# Transfer domain and DNS from Azure to Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cloudflare

I want to transfer a domain (.uk) from Azure to Cloudflare. Both the domain and DNS hosting is on Azure.

- Cloudflare require the DNS resolution to be moved to them prior to the domain transfer.
- Cloudflare need the existing Azure DNS servers removed from the DNS record and replaced with Cloudflare ones.

Editing the DNS record in Azure doesn't allow the Azure DNS servers to be removed, only the Cloudflare ones to be added at the end. This isn't sufficient for Cloudflare to allow the transfer.

[This question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/784472/transfer-domain-created-on-azure-to-cloudflare.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171637/how-to-transfer-out-a-domain-from-microsoft-azure) both state to select the "Advanced Management Portal" under "Domain Management". But I don't have that option, only "Domain Renewal".

Where is the new management screen to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The "Advanced Management Portal" no longer shows in the UI (for reasons unknown), but it can be accessed here: https://dcc.secureserver.net/domains

[image: Advanced Management Portal]

2. My Azure login email wasn't recognised as a valid username. Use"Need to find your username" and follow the instructions, the result was a numeric ID customer #.
3. Use "Need to find your password" to reset the password for that customer #.
4. Login using the new details

Once logged in the portal allows you to:

1. Fully manage the DNS server settings for the domain (removing the Azure entries)
2. Removing domain locking (to allow transfer)
3. Allow the setting of the IPS tag to allow the domain transfer to Cloudflare